# Input box used to copy cell and insert at bottom

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list that has a certain amount of rows and contain formulas in the rows.  I have an input box that will ask the user how many additional lines they would like entered and it adds them to the top.  I would like to change this to copy the rows (with formulas and no values) and paste them at the bottom of the worksheet above the "add more lines above" row I have with the button.  I am stuck, please help:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim j As Long, r As Range

    On Error GoTo Canceled
    j = InputBox("Type the Number of Rows to be Inserted")
    Set r = Range("A1")

    Do
        Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
        Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
        If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
    Loop
Canceled:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 4/19: code now adds lines to the bottom of the data block (rather than the top):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim j As Long, Index As Long, LastRow As Long, _
    LastCol As Long
Dim r As Range, DragDown As Range
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet

'set variables up front for easy reference
Set MyWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastCol = MyWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
LastRow = MyWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set r = Range(MyWorksheet.Cells(LastRow, 1), MyWorksheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

On Error GoTo Canceled
j = InputBox("Type the Number of Rows to be Inserted")

'simulate user dragging the bottom row down
Set DragDown = Range(MyWorksheet.Cells(LastRow, 1), MyWorksheet.Cells(LastRow + j, LastCol))
r.AutoFill Destination:=DragDown

Canceled:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, It is still adding the rows to the top of my sheet, not the lower end.  Also, I am looking to copy the formulas that are in the cells in the rows and have those in the new inserted rows as well.

Comment: So essentially you'd like your user to input N rows, and the code should simulate the user dragging the formulas down from the last row N addition rows -- right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I have 32 rows open and row 33 has the button that will call the macro.  I would like the new rows to be added above the "insert rows" button call.

Comment: The code has been updated to add rows to the bottom, with formulas. Hope that works!